# jquery mobile prevent page change depending on calling page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to prevent a page change in jquery mobile depending on what page the user is currently on but I dont know what is in the data.options object. So basically I need to say if the user is going to index.html AND the calling page is example.html then prevent default.

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforeload", function (event, data) {
  var toPage = data.toPage;
  if (toPage == 'undefined') {
    return;
  } else {
    //need additional condition to see current page in the data.objections object?
  if (toPage == '/android_asset/www/index.html');
  event.preventdefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You actually want to use the `pagebeforechange` event.

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    var to = data.toPage,
        from = data.options.fromPage;

    if (typeof to === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
        if (from) from = '#' + from.attr('id');

        if (from === '#page1' && to === '#page3') {
            alert('Cannot change to page 3 from page 1');
            e.preventDefault();

            // remove active class on button
            // otherwise button would remain highlighted
            $.mobile.activePage
                .find('.ui-btn-active')
                .removeClass('ui-btn-active');
        }            
    }
});
```

I've created a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/zMnUM/

Comment: Note that in jQM 1.3.2 (running in Chrome on desktop), the data argument's .toPage property is not a url but an object, and the name of the page is to be found at data.toPage['0'].id

Comment: I think it's a URL the first call and an object the second call.  This event gets called twice per navigation.