# How can I disable jQueryMobile page changes in certain cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, asset-pipeline

I'm writing a Rails application, and I'm using jQueryMobile for the mobile views.

Most of the time, I want to allow JQM to manipulate the DOM by adding and removing 'pages' as per usual. However, in certain cases, I'd like to override the default behavior, and perform some simple DOM manipulations of my own.

For example, I have a list of users, each of which will have an 'Add to Contacts' link/form.

```
<ul data-role='listview'>

  <li>
    <span class='name' id="user_56757234">Jim</span>
    <form action="/contacts" class="new_contact_form" data-remote="true" data-type="json" id="new_contact_form_56757234" method="post">
      <!-- form info here -->
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
    </form>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class='name' id="user_975827294">Fred</span>
    <form action="/contacts" class="new_contact_form" data-remote="true" data-type="json" id="new_contact_form_975827294" method="post">
      <!-- form info here -->
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
    </form>
  </li>

  <!-- etc... -->

</ul>
```

After the user clicks to add a given contact, assuming the request is successful, the given form should disappear, indicating that the contact has been added.

I need to conform to standard Rails RESTFUL style controllers, so these forms will submit to a ContactsController create action, which will return, let's say, a JSON representation of the new contact.

Again, I want to block JQM from attempting to insert a new page -- I just want to delete the specific form that triggered the event. But I don't want to disable the standard JQM behavior that I depend upon elsewhere.

Is there a clean, simple way to do this?

I gather the 'pagebeforeload' event is my friend, but I'm unclear how to set this up.

This post seems relevant ( [jquery mobile prevent page change depending on calling page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613833/jquery-mobile-prevent-page-change-depending-on-calling-page) ) ...but am I correct that this is a global setting? Seems like overkill in my case.

It's a Rails 3.1 project so ideally I could set this up in the controller-specific javascript assets file, in a way that plays nice with standard Rails-UJS.

Any help would be much appreciated,

warmly,

Comment: So... solution, in retrospect, was pretty obvious. DIY, give JQM a rest

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$('#new_contacts').live('pageinit', function(event) {
  $('.new_contact_form_mobile').submit(function(e) {  
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var request = $.ajax("/contacts", {
      type: "POST", 
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
      form.fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-ajax="false"` as an attribute in your form tag. This will disable JQuery Mobile's ajax behavior and allow you to do a ajax call in Rails.